# Запрет чтения .txt файлов через браузер .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, permissions

Привет , Интересует код в .htaccess который запретит читать файлы из определенной папки , либо читать файлы с расширением .txt если открыть их с браузера , или альтернативный вариант с правами доступа , в данный момент стоит 644.

//это относится к теме ниже..

вот , не хотят работать вместе

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^index.php$ /az/ [NC,R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php

<FilesMatch "\.css$">
  Order Deny,Allow
  Deny from all
</FilesMatch>
```

Comment: Вопросы не надо менять после получения ответа. Если возник новый вопрос, то его надо оформлять отдельно.

Comment: да , но так как это идентичная тема с различием только в формате файла , при оформлении нового вопроса также мне скажут , что это дубликат "нынешнего" вопроса

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Положите в нужную папку (в которой хотите запретить доступ к файлам с расширением txt) файл .htaccess с таким содержимым:

```
<FilesMatch "\.txt$">
  Order Deny,Allow
  Deny from all
</FilesMatch>
```

Comment: спасибо , разве этот код не запрещает для всех пользователей? тк у меня из этой папки , php(FAST CGI работает от самого пользователя) , читает содержимое этих файлов и выводит на сайт , он не перестанет работать?

Comment: @S1lllver, если вы из php обращаетесь к файлам как на локальном диске, то эти запреты не действуют. Запреты устанавливаются для внешних запросов к серверу.

Comment: проверил все работает , есть определенная страница , где вводишь текст и все такое она изменяет содержимое этого файла , к которому собственно я прописал запрет

Comment: но я уже проверил , все работает , отлично

Comment: этот скрипт , понимаю что это не логично , но не работает для .css файлов что очень странно , есть основной .htaccess который делает перенаправления и все такое , я добавил к нему но он не хочет запрещать просмотр css файлов , код основного .htaccess напишу вверху

Comment: @S1lllver, а скажите мне зачем запрещать доступ к css файлам если браузер их должен скачивать для правильного отображения страницы?

Comment: я знаю ) но меня интересует , возможно ли сделать так , чтобы пользователь введя адрес .css файла не смог прочитать его содержимое , но браузер его скачивал и отображал.

Comment: @S1lllver, нельзя этого сделать. Все что отображается/скачивается браузером будет доступно пользователю.

Comment: странно , помню читал в какой-то статье что можно скрыть отображение css файла , не могу вспомнить в какой